# Find the unique number

Tags: code-golf

I have read a question similar to this. I found it interesting, and difficult  so I rephrased the question as a code golf. (that question is closed )

Challenge:

> In 1 million and 1 numbers, all the numbers having the duplicate except only one number . Write a program that can find this unique number.

Input form:

> a text file containing 1000001 integer seperated by space. 
>   The numbers are shuffled

Output form:

> a single number

Note:
Using standard library functions to compare values is not allowed the (in case you intend to use something as `strcmp()` in c or anything similar in other languages)
a simple algorithm that can achieve the job.

This is code golf, so the shortest code win.
All languages are allowed. ( I prefer c/c   x86 assembly if possible because i have no experience in any other language) 
add some explanation to your source code if possible.

Good luck.

Comment: You might want to further define comparison operators. Now I can just do `f=open('f').read().split();
[i for i in f if f.count(i)&2][0]` and be done with it.

Comment: Capitalisation and some line breaks, please!

Comment: What does it mean that "*all the numbers have a duplicate except one*"? Does it mean that every number occurs 0, 1, or 2 times? Or could the input be `1 1 1 2`? Also, what is the range of integers permitted in the input?

Comment: This mean that there is 2 exact copies of 1000000 number in the txt file and one copy of single number 
example of input file
1 3 6 5 1 5 6 3 2 
each number is doubled except 2 
there is no limits for that inters in the file but they are all integers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Golfscript, 6 characters

```
~]{^}*
```

This simply XORs all numbers: assuming the input file consists of the numbers `a b b c c d d ...` in any order, this calculates `a^b^b^c^c^d^d^...` (XOR is commutative/associative, so the order of numbers doesn't matter). Since `x^x == 0`, this effectively leaves only the number that hasn't been duplicated.

Run it like this: `golfscript unique.gs < inputfile`

Comment: I am totally beginner so i need more explanation

Comment: @Ahmed I added some explanation, does that make it clearer?

Comment: Yes It is clear now 
thanks

Comment: This is extraordinarily clever (and not gs-only)

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth/blob/master/pyth.py), 10 characters

Note: Does not fail even if there are more than 2 copies of duplicated numbers.

```
JPw)'ocJNJ
```

Explanation:

```
JPw)    J=input.split()
'oJNJ   print first element of J sorted by count of element in J.
```